# MYSQL make a table group of collection

Tags: mysql

im not sure how i should write for the title. But i've found a case as below:

```
table name: student

    | ID | FAVORITE | NAME   | BIRTHDATE |
    |----|----------|--------|-----------|
    |    | MATH     | JOHN   |     12/06 |
    |    | CHEM     | RYAN   |     11/07 |
    |    | MATH     | OODA   |      4/09 |
    |    | HISTORY  | YINYIN |     25/05 |
```

how to make a new table that grouping the name based on their favorite lesson with mysql?

```
table name: favorite

    | FAVORITE | NAME       |
    |----------|------------|
    | MATH     | JOHN, OODA |
    | CHEM     | RYAN       |
    | HISTORY  | YINYIN     |
```

Comment: I think you're looking for GROUP_CONCAT, see [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use an aggregation query with the help of `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```sql
SELECT FAVORITE, GROUP_CONCAT(NAME) AS NAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY FAVORITE;
```