# mysql collecting the name based on favorite and sorting the collected name with subsort

Tags: mysql

Prevously I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74861445/mysql-make-a-table-group-of-collection), but after re-read it, I realised it's more complicated so I'm asking a new question here.

I have following table: how to sort the table based on collecting the name from the same favorite, and also sorting the name based on their sum of score?

```
table: student
| FAVORITE | NAME   | score1 | score2 |  
|----------|--------|--------|--------|  
| math     | john   |     98 |     97 |  
| chem     | ryan   |     97 |    100 |  
| history  | yinyin |     80 |     95 |  
| math     | oda    |     99 |    100 |  
| history  | ed     |     67 |     85 |
```

expected result table after querying collecting name, and also sorting name:

```
table:favorite
| FAVORITE | NAME       |
|----------|------------|
| math     | john, oda  |
| chem     | ryan       |
| history  | ed, yinyin |
```

i've tried this:

```sql
SELECT FAVORITE, GROUP_CONCAT(
    select name from (
        select name, sum(score1 + score2) as total_score
        from student
        group by name
        order by total_score asc
    ) as T
) AS NAME
FROM student
GROUP BY FAVORITE;
```

please help, thank you.

Comment: @ErgestBasha no, cannot. please read my question carefullly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to provide the required value to order by using a derived table first, then specify the order in the *group_concat* syntax:

```
select FAVORITE, group_concat(NAME order by tot separator ', ') Name
from (
  select *, score1 + score2 tot
  from t
)t
group by FAVORITE;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SxZ2A3gW)

Comment: @dhanyn10 The solution doesn't match the expected result you provided in the question.

Comment: @Yevgen im already tested this solution from the demo fiddle. im also test your solution from your own sqlfiddle with the different score but your solution failed.

Comment: @Yevgen see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48edd75/19

Comment: @dhanyn10 Sorry, but the fiddle you provided is identical to mine, you haven't changed anything.

Comment: @Yevgen read the result carefully, best_student column at first and the third row. first row ordered from the lowest to highest, and the third row is just the opposite

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Your Previous question's accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74861478/7534856), just add `order by (score1+score2)`.

```
SELECT FAVORITE, GROUP_CONCAT(NAME order by (`score1`+`score2`)) AS NAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY FAVORITE;
```

Comment: also sorting the name based on their sum of score